# linenumbers of minted are not shown in beamer if i use infolines

Tags: beamer, minted

linenumbers of minted are not shown in beamer if i use infolines as an outertheme

example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{\vskip2pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Hello}
\begin{minted}[linenos]{c}
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("hello\n");
}
\end{minted}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Great question, and thanks for providing a complete MWE, it really helps folks trying to debug :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is caused because the numbers are set in the margin, but with the `infolines` theme, the margin is too small. It does

```
\setbeamersize{text margin left=1em,text margin right=1em}
```

Reverting the margins back to the defaults of `1cm` is one way to fix the problem, and may or may not be satisfactory to you:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=1cm,text margin right=1cm}
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{\vskip2pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Hello}
\begin{minted}[linenos]{c}
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("hello\n");
}
\end{minted}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve the same thing (without changing and restoring the beamer margins), is using the `xleftmargin` option of the `minted` package:

`\setminted{xleftmargin=1cm}`

This has the same effect, but only shifts the listings according to the margin setting.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}

% set the left margin of C listings to 1cm
\setminted[c]{xleftmargin=1cm}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{\vskip2pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Hello}
\begin{minted}[linenos]{c}
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("hello\n");
}
\end{minted}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The `xrightmargin` option applies to the margin to the right of the listing respectively.